# Can't get all with this query in Node.js and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, backend

I'm trying to create a route for my api to return all the items in a shop but only with the category given in the url params.

But i'm getting this error when using the route in postman

`Cast to ObjectId failed for value "shirt" at path "_id" for model "clothes"`

This is the code, I'm using node.js, express and mongoose.

```
//GET ALL BY CATEGORY

router.get('/:category', async (req, res)=>{
  try{
    const categoryClothes = await Clothes.find(
      {type:req.params.category  })
      res.send(categoryClothes)
  }
  catch(err){
    console.log(err.message)
  }
})
```

Mongoose Schema

```
const Clothes = mongoose.model('clothes', new mongoose.Schema({
  price: Number,
  name:{
    type: String,
    lowercase: true,
    required: true
  },
  size: {
    type: Array,
    lowercase: true
  },
  picture: {
    type:String,
    required:true
  },
  footsize:{
    type: Array
  },
  type:{
    type: String,
    enum:['jacket', 'sneaker', 'hat', 'shirt', 'pants'],
    lowercase: true,
    required: true

  }, 
  sex:{
    type: String,
    enum: ['m', 'f', 'unisex'],
    lowercase: true,
    required: true
  }
}))
```

Comment: Can you show us your schema and a sample document?

Comment: > Cast to ObjectId failed for value "shirt" at path "_id" for model "clothes"

I guess you have one document something like `{ _id: "shirt" ...}`, you should fix that one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i had a route before this one that had /:id and it was entering there always and trying to find the category in _id.

My solution was to move the /:category route before the /:id

But if anyone can explain me the reason why this was happening i would much appreciate.

Comment: It does... thats's what's bothering me. Idk why

Comment: i changed the code tho, instead of using params i'm using querys